# How can I get specific links in a class?

Tags: c#, html

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="YazarDetayTarih_Conteiner">
    <div class="YazarDetayTarih FL">30.Mart.2013, Cumartesi</div>
    <div class="YazarDetayBaslik FL">
<a class="haberlink"  href="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/yazarlar/22928436.asp">Böyle özür olmaz Serdar Ortaç</a>
       </div>
     </div>
<div class="YazarDetayTarih_Conteiner">
<div class="YazarDetayTarih_Conteiner">
```

There are a couple div class="YazarDetayTarih_Conteiner"> . and I want to get these href links. Currently when I write like

```
HtmlElementCollection col = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement el in col)
{
       link = el.GetAttribute("href");
}
```

It gives all a href links at the page. How can I specifically take only href which belongs to \a class="haberlink"

edit : I couldnt make it work. after I try richTextBox1.Text += el.GetAttribute("class") it gives blank page.

while using nodes we can do like SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'haberlink')]"); is there any way to do this?

Comment: Get the class first and check if it matches.

Comment: @MattBurland wont it be too slow if it ll check all entries? and which value  do I need to check? if(el.getAttribute("class")=="haberlink") ?

Comment: There is no shortcut to searching this collection that doesn't involve looking at the members of the collection. If you know (or only want) one result, you can short cut your loop by `break`ing when you find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your foreach loop, skip the ones not having the desired class:

```
if(el.GetAttribute("class") != "haberlink")
   continue;
```

Comment: thanks. but still couldnt get the link when I try                                                                                                                   if(el.GetAttribute("class") != "haberlink")
                      continue;
                  richTextBox1.Text += el.GetAttribute("href");

Comment: I guess I solved the issue. it should be "classname"